# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

I am having this problem when I am trying to create android listview. If I insert the codes for listview then the app is not opened, it shown unfortunately the app has stopped and if I remove codes for that listview, everything is fine.

Here is my MainActivity.java file. I have other files too but haven't made any changes to them so I think the problem is in this file. What is the problem here?

```
package com.isudip.task3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button btn;

    //button on the start page
    public void summary(){
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent summaryView = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Summary.class);
                startActivity(summaryView);
            }
        });
    }

    //adding list

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        summary();

        ListView listView;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.team_list);
        String[] values = new String[]{
                "Item 1",
                "Item 2",
                "Item 3",
                "Item 4"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), City.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Arsenal.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

edit: Sorry, I forgot to update my logcat, here it is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.isudip.task3, PID: 9214
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.isudip.task3/com.isudip.task3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.isudip.task3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Anytime you have a crash, you should grab the stacktrace from LogCat and inspect it first.

Comment: just edited my question with the logcat, sorry for the mistake and please take a look now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are having a NullPointerException at

```
com.isudip.task3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
```

In Line 48, you use your listView:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

That means, listView is Null (not initialized). You try to initialize it by getting it from the layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
ListView listView;
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.team_list);
```

It seems the listView with the id `team_list` can not be found in the layout named `activity_main`, as [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) may return Null in this case.

Check if there is a ListView called `team_list` in your layout.

Comment: that makes sense, my ListView is in another xml file and I was stupid enough to call it from my MainActivity. thanks a ton, I moved the codes related to my ListView to that java class and everything works fine...

Answer (score 0):

As you `startActivityForResult`,you need to override the method `onActivityResult` to handle response.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
    // Make sure the request was successful
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // The user picked a contact.
        // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

        // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: forgot to add the logcat at first, can you please take another look??

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);  Define adapter like this and then assign to listView.

Comment: did you try to override onActivityResult method?.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for helping. The problem was very silly. I was trying to call my ListView from my MainActivity but the listview was in another xml that's why the problem was there, now moved the codes of my listview to that related java class and everything is fine now.